# Python 2.6.1 (OS X 10.6.8) re.sub() underscore behavior in groups?

Tags: python, regex, backreference

I have a situation where I may encounter "{key " or "{key\n" and I want to convert the "{key\n" to "{key " without affecting other instances of "\n" in the string. key may contain any of a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore, dash.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
import re
test = '{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b_\nbar}\n{sq-c_ gluck}'
print re.sub(r'(\{*[_a-zA-Z0-9-]\n)','\1 ',test)
```

it returns this:

```
{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b bar}
{sq-c_ gluck}
```

...where there is an invisible character, `0x01`, right where the underscore should be in the replacement.

I *expected* this:

```
{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b_ bar}
{sq-c_ gluck}
```

So my questions are, where did the underscore after `sq-b` go? Where did that `0x01` come from?

- The underscore matched, obviously, as it was replaced
- it's within the parens so it's in group 1
- group 1 is what came out in the replacement (sans underscore)

Comment: As this is not shown in your question, did you acknowledge that the missing underscore has been converted to u'\x01'?

Comment: Mathias, I don't understand what you're asking or trying to tell me? What does the ordinal value 1 have to do with anything?

Comment: I don't know, it’s just an observation that, when running your code, the resulting string contains '\x01' at the precise place you’d expect an '_'

Comment: OH! I see it now, I will update the question. SUPER job of looking into the issue, I didn't even think of invisible characters!

Comment: Using named groups like re.sub(r'((?P<one>\{[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)\n(?P<two>[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\}))','\g<one> \g<two>',test) does what you want - however note that I tested this with python 3.4.3 but using python 2 regex syntax as shown at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html.

Comment: No, it doesn't -- this can't depend on a closing `}` as there may be others nested. I specifically need to locate "`{key\n`" and replace it with "`{key "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes, you captured the `\n` and you forgot the `r` in your sub string:

```
import re
test = '{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b_\nbar}\n{sq-c_ gluck}'
print re.sub(r'(\{*[_a-zA-Z0-9-])\n',r'\1 ',test)
```

Also, as @remus stated, you can replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w` so you can simplify to:

```
re.sub(r'(\{*[\w-])\n', r'\1 ', test)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Concise and correct. Solid, brother. :)

Comment: Accepting it has more value than a comment, then ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's check out your original expression:

`\{*` matches 0 or more of literal `{`. In this case, because it's expecting the next character is one of these `_a-zA-Z0-9-` followed by a `\n`, it captures the *last* character before the `\n` and effectively renders the `\{*` statement irrelevant.

And then, since `\n` is included in your capture group along with that single other character, when you replace it with `\1` backreference, the newline is included in the replacement along with that other character. In this case, you're replacing `_\n` with a space, and that's why the space is disappearing.

This gets me the answer including underscore - if you want to replace the line break, you need to exclude it from the capture group. Also, silly me, I missed the lack of literal string `r''` prefix on the backreference:

```
import re
test = '{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b_\nbar}\n{sq-c_ gluck}'
print re.sub(r'(\{[^}]+)\n(.+\})',r'\1 \2',test)
```

Output:

```
{sq-a_ foo}{sq-b_ bar}
{sq-c_ gluck}
```

Also of note - you can simply your expression by using `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z_` ;)

All of this said, I think there could be a much easier way of obtaining your goal:

```
re.sub(r'(?!\})\n', ' ', test);
```

... would replace all instances of newline not preceded by a `}`. Depending on what you're trying to do, that might be much simpler.

Another alternative is to use a negative lookbehind:

```
re.sub(r'(?![\w-])(\n)', ' ', test);
```

Comment: No, that's not an ok (or correct) result. The whole point is to replace that line break with a space. The results I expected and need are detailed in the question. I tried what you suggest, by the way, got the same results you did, which is the replacement does not occur.

Comment: UH, ok nevermind I see the hidden characters now. That's goofing things up.

Comment: I'll try to generalize your edited answer back to what I want to do; the presence of a closing `}` cannot be part of the evaluation. If I can get it to work, I'll be back to vote up your answer. :)

Comment: Silly me. Didn't notice the missing literal `r''` on the back reference. See update.

Comment: No success. And I still don't understand wtf is happening to that underscore.

Comment: Also, changing the `'\1 '` into `r'\1 '` causes the find portion of the sub to fail.

Comment: Just to follow up, I think your first para is still incorrect. `\{*` isn't the meaningful sequence, is it? The `*` precedes what it's saying "any number of" about, so for instance, `*.` means any number of any char. So my re is literal `{` (as `\{`) followed by "any number of" `_a-zA-Z0-9-` followed by a newline -- Yes? No? As I describe it, aside from the incorrect capture of the `\n` and so its re-appearance in the output, both of which I fixed as per Mathias, below, and the non-raw string for the replace, does work as I wanted it to.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're saying but they first paragraph is correct.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but let's see. I'm talking about where you said this: "`\{*` matches 0 or more of literal `{`." It doesn't. `*\{` would match 1 or more of literal `{`. `\{*` is one escaped character, followed by a an asterisk, which means "any number of the *following* character, which in this case is represented by the set `[\w-]` The way you seem to be describing it, you're assuming the `*` applies to the preceding character, and as far as I know, that's not how it works. Clearer?

Comment: No, asterisk means any number of the preceding character.

Comment: Then why does `\{*[\w-]` match `{f` and `{foo` ? I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here... appreciate your continued patience with me, too. :)

Comment: That means 0 or more { followed by any one of: letter, number, underscore or hyphen.

Comment: I figured it out. `\w` is a word match, not a character match so the asterisk wasn't needed, so the fact that it didn't apply forward was irrelevant. Thanks again.